# How can i plot the data which in text file?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, plot, text

I have a complicated text format output file named DATA_out (like the example below downside) and i'm taking between two line (for example values and total) data inside the file and saving as a excel file. I made a start line and end line with user input . When my code running it take the data which i want and save as a excel file. Here is the problem, there are 3 columns named column 1,2,3 in data text but in xlsx file i have just one column. Because of that i cant plot graphic.

Do you have any suggestions for divide column by column with coding? Here what i have.

```
DATA_out file
      values
    DATA_LINE1 column1 column2 column3
    DATA_LINE2 column1 column2 column3
    DATA_LINE3 column1 column2 column3
    DATA_LINE4 column1 column2 column3
total
```

---

```
# Spyder Editor (Python 3.7)
import pandas as pd #Libraries
import os

#Receiving input data for the range in which the scanned text file will be selected.
start = input('Start: ')
end = input('Finish: ')
print('\n')

ffile = open("DATA_out.txt")

lines = [] #List to be filled

for line in ffile: #Finding the starting line
    if start in line:
        break

for line in ffile: #Finding the finish line
    if end in line:
        break

    lines.append(line)  # Filling the list                         

else: 
    lines = []
    print('Wrong input')

if lines: #output as a file
    print("".join(lines))
    with open('DatasText.txt', 'w') as ffile:
        for ddata in lines:
            ffile.write("%s" % ddata)

df = pd.read_table('DatasText.txt') #txt to excell format
df.to_excel('Datas.xlsx', 'Sheet1', index=False)
os.remove('DatasText.txt')
```

Comment: Is there [whitespace](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.whitespace) in any of the columns? Are the columns separated with a space or a tab?

Comment: @wwii there is no columns, just one column and all data is in this column. i mean, normally i have 3 columns but when i convert the text file to excel file all columns became one column. i can't fix it still.

Answer (score 1):

I Assumed data existed like this in text file and named it test.txt.

```
DATA_LINE1 column1 column2 column3
DATA_LINE2 column1 column2 column3
DATA_LINE3 column1 column2 column3
DATA_LINE4 column1 column2 column3
```

Now this is my code to push it into excel file:

```
import pandas as pd

df = {'dataline':[],'column1':[],'column2':[],'column3':[]}
data = ''
with open('test.txt','r') as f:
    data = f.read()

for line in data.split('\n'):
    x = line.split(' ')
    df['dataline'].append(x[0])
    df['column1'].append(x[1])
    df['column2'].append(x[2])
    df['column3'].append(x[3])

df = pd.DataFrame(df)
print(df)
df.to_excel('data.xlsx')
```

Output:

```
     dataline  column1  column2  column3
0  DATA_LINE1  column1  column2  column3
1  DATA_LINE2  column1  column2  column3
2  DATA_LINE3  column1  column2  column3
3  DATA_LINE4  column1  column2  column3
```

Excel file image:

[image: Excel image]

Comment: `data = f.read()` - You could use `f.readlines()` then you wouldn't need to split on `\n`. Also OP's code already *gathers* the valid lines into a list named `lines` - maybe you should use that.